# How can I use Nokia Maps in a WP7 (Mango) app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, here-api

I want to use Nokia Maps on my WP7 app (Mango) but it is not supported yet by Nokia I believe,  does anyone ever use this product on WP7 app? Do I have to use it with Browser Control?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it's possible yet, maybe under apollo with the app-to-app communication, but atm you can't combine 2 3rd-party(nokia included) apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two option :

1. You can use nokia map library (http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Nokia_Maps_for_WP7_using_Bing_Map_Control)
2. you can use image control and set the source to "http://m.nokia.me/?c=" + p.placeLatitude + "," + p.placeLongitude + "&t=0&z=15&h=150&w=480&nord".